# How to change IP dynamically in hadoop conf.xml

Tags: shell, ip, pattern-matching

```
cat test.xml |sed -r 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b'/$ip_address/ >new.xml
```

Here, I am trying to replace pattern matching IP with new IP address. I am getting

unterminated  `s` command. Please let me know what is going wrong

Comment: does your $ip_address have CIDR form ?

Comment: no,I am just passing IP as an arguement My file is <configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/usr/lib/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://103.8.126.191:8020</value>
</property>
</configuration>
I just need to replace 103.8.126.191 with new IP as an arg

Comment: Your command works for me.

Comment: Yes,I just checked.thx a lot